# Operator overloading multiple operands to return class list

Tags: python, operator-overloading

How do I write code for a class in python that overloads add as follows:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value

  def __add__(self,other):
    return [self.value, other.value]
```

This works for two operands but how do I make it work for multiple operands, so:

```
a1 = A(10)
a2 = A(20)
a3 = A(30)
print a1 + a2 + a3
```

Should return [a1, a2, a3]

That is the add function should return list of class A, with every '+' adding to the list

Answer (score 2):

In order to what you're trying to accomplish, you will need to overload both `__add__` and `__radd__`, and also checking if the other value is type `list`, to append the `self.value` to that list.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __add__(self, other):
    return [self.value, other.value]

  def __radd__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, list):
      return other + [self.value]
    return [other, self.value]

a1 = A(10)
a2 = A(20)
a3 = A(30)
print (a1 + a2 + a3)
# [10, 20, 30]
```

---

The reason why why yours does not work is because:

```
print a1 + a2 + a3
```

First evaluates `a1 + a2`, which results the correct answer, `[10, 20]`. But immediately after, the next operation that was ran was `[10, 20] + a3` which calls the list's `__add__`, not the `A` class's.

That's why you need to define the `__radd__` to make it use `A` class's addition instead.

Comment: This is a neat solution, I wasn't familiar with __radd__!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this what is returned from your add function is not an instance of the `A` class. You could call the constructor around A, and add 
the items to the list if this is what you want.  You also need to check that the value is not an instance of list otherwise you will return `[[10, 20,] 30]`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self,other):
        if isinstance(self.value, list):
            vals =[val for val in self.value]
            vals.append(other.value)
            return A(vals)
        return A([self.value, other.value])
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


a1 = A(10)
a2 = A(20)
a3 = A(30)
print(a1 + a2 + a3)
```

prints `[10, 20, 30]`

If you want the direct list concatenation, just use lists?

```
a1 = [10]
a2 = [20]
a3 = [30]
print a1 + a2 + a3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break up the logic of the overloading like this:

```
a1 +  (a2 + a3)
      separate instance
```

You can implement this like so:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, val):
      self.val = val
      self.cummulative = [val]
   def flatten(self, val):
       if isinstance(val, int):
            yield val
       else:
           for i in val:
              for b in self.flatten(i):
                  yield b
   def __add__(self, instance):
      self.cummulative.append(instance.cummulative)
      return A(self.cummulative)
   def __str__(self):
       return repr(list(self.flatten(self.cummulative)))

a1 = A(40)
a2 = A(50)
a3 = A(60)
val = a1+a2+a3
print(val)
```

Output:

```
[40, 50, 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

so like modesiit commented, your issue is that **add** is returning a list initially. So after that you are running into the error because you are trying to add a list and an object of class A. I'm not sure why you're wanting to do this, but I did the following and got your expected results:

```
class A(list):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        super(A, self).__init__([value])
```

Essentially, this creates a new list subclass that now has a value attribute on the list object itself. Now everything functions exactly like it did before with no overloading. In this case though, you will still have issues down the line with the fact that the returned value is of type list not of type A. You could end up doing something like overloading `__add__` to call the super like normal but cast as type A later if you wanted to, but you would need to adjust the `__init__` method accordingly